# Changing PRODUCT_NAME results in 'Objective C module not found' error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have two targets for my customs Framework, codebase is identical for both but min. deployment target version is different.

Targets:

1. `MyFramework-Debug`: Product Name: **`MyFramework_Debug`** Product Module Name: `MyFramework`
2. `MyFramework-Release`: Product Name: `MyFramework` Product Module Name: `MyFramework`

Now issue is, I have hybrid code base with C++ / Objective C / Swift. I have imported some of my Objective C headers to Umbrella header MyFramework.h. And **Defines Modules = YES**

Now when I compile and run Release Target it works fine. But when I compile Debug Target it shows error `<unknown>:0: error: underlying Objective-C module 'MyFramework' not found`.

I have double checked the build folder, I see valid Module in auto generated moudlemap file and I see that umbrella header is exported under my framework `MyFramework_Debug.framework/Headers`.

Why is this happening? I have kept `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` same hence it should just work right? Changing only `PRODUCT_NAME` should only change the framework folder's name and shouldn't actually affect the code right? What am I missing?

***PS:**
if I keep debug target's product name the same, i.e. `MyFramework`, then when I build whole project it says multiple commands generate file. (Both targets writing to same framework?)*

**Side note:**

*Why two targets with identical codebase?
I'm using metal, and most of the Metal classes are not supported on simulator < iOS13, but my Framework is intended to have deployment target iOS11. Hence, I have two targets:*

1. *`MyFramework-Debug`: Device + Simulator min version: iOS 13*
2. *`MyFramework-Release`: Device only min version: iOS 11
   My client app has min version iOS11, hence it ensures that other devs who work on code base can run the app in simulator without having to worry about Framework's support.*

Comment: Thank you for the pointer towards `PRODUCT_NAME`! I was getting the same error, and setting `PRODUCT_NAME` to match `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` fixed it. Luckily, that configuration is acceptable to me.

Comment: @imshrey Hello! 
How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @chchrn, actually I didn't, I ended up wrapping my unsupported code in #if blocks and henced used only one target with module name and product name to be same.